# Does mapping a new drive influence the execution of the other batches in the master batch?

Tags: batch-file

So I have a master batch file in what I call 2 batches. The first one is mapping a new drive, and the other one is using an batch from that mapped drive.
As far as I know the batches should the batches should execute one after another (after the batch one is executed, the batch 2 is executing). But my problem is after the batch 1 is executed all other commands that I had written after it are not executed.

```
call mapping
set root = F:\a\b
pushd root
echo The current directory is %CD%
call batch2
pause
```

Do you know if the mapping can influence the order of execution of the batches ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: At the end of `mapping`, replace `EXIT` with `EXIT /B`, or remove `EXIT` in favor of `GOTO :EOF`. You should also consider doing the same thing with `batch2`. Then change `set root = F:\a\b` to `Set "root=F:\a\b"`, and `pushd root` to `PushD "%root%"`. If my guesses of your issues above are incorrect, please post the content of `mapping` and `batch2` as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60719998/edit) to your question, so that we do not have to guess any more.

Comment: A) `set root = F:\a\b` = wrong syntax (remove the spaces). B) `pushd root` - you probably want `pushd %root%`? C) after `pushd`, your `batch2` probably isn't found (you are in another folder)